# Parsing XML - line feed, carriage return??? I'm confused?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, jquery

Ok, I have search for about 3 hours and have decided to post this. I am pulling a XML feed and have one XML element that has a bunch of text creating one paragraph. When I look at the source though, I see it broken with carriage returns (as mentioned in the title, not sure if that's correct).

Here is the feed I am pulling from: http://jobs.cbizsoft.com/cbizjobs/jobdetail_post.aspx?cid=cbiz_advantech&jobid=Req-0005

I am using php to build the xml file and then jquery/ajax to build the page as needed.

My question is if I can use php to parse the breaks and format the output to look nicer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: hi joe, xml with carriage return shouldn't affect anything as long as it's a valid xml. unless you're trying to display the xml data as it is...

Comment: can we see all or at least some of your script (the relevant part(s) that is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand you correctly, the problem is when the text is output in your HTML document, then the line breaks are gone. This is because in HTML line breaks (like all white space) is collapse into one space, so

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

and

```
<div>Hello 

World!</div>
```

produce the same output.

There are several ways you can solve this:

- Put the CSS style [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop)`: pre-line` (or `pre-wrap`) on the surrounding element.
- Or use PHP to replace all line breaks with `<br>`
- Or use a [markdown](http://www.google.de/search?q=markdown) library that basically does the same as the second point, but with additional kinds of formatting such as properly wrapping paragraphs or turn bullet lists in a real HTML list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be honest, I think I was staring at this way too long because I didn't even stop to think about addressing this via CSS. Thanks again as well as everyone else who answered...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a CDATA section for the description data so that any offending characters are ignored by XML parsers

```
<Item name='Description' caption='Description'>
<![CDATA[
- Support acquisition and installation processes and coordinate with multiple SPAWAR and Navy stakeholders.
- Analyze acquisition policy life cycle and  provide analytical support.  

...

]]>
</Item>
```

Melaos is correct that carriage returns (and other whitespace characters) are valid within XML documents

Answer (score 0):

See the [**`nl2br()`**](http://php.net/nl2br) function, which will put HTML line breaks for each actual line in the text.

Here's a [quicky example with your XML](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EYZhWh).